# testing whether a function is virtual or is a constructor

Tags: c++, reflection, coding-style, constructor, destructor

I was reading [Never Call Virtual Functions during Construction or Destruction](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/nevercall.html) by Scott Meyer about basic C++ usage.

I was wondering if g++ has some compiler flags to warn about this bad coding that is really effective. If not what could be a way to code to do this  check?

If I would code such kind of check I would approach this job by using a stack and inserting a piece of information at each call (a way to implement a call stack.

What  I still need is a way to test whether a function is a virtual or whether a function is a constructor: Is there anyway to do that that you know? Something similar to a .NET 'reflection' idea?

Comment: Did you try `-Weffc++`? Not sure it covers that case but it should be simple for the compiler.

Comment: You do get a warning on pure virtual functions -- `warning: pure virtual virtual ... called from constructor`.

Comment: @krynr - -Weffc++ = mindblown!! I thought you were being sarcastic but there's an actual "-Weffc++" wow!!

Comment: @krynr: That's amazing; I had no idea that existed!

Comment: @OliCharlesworth It's even a checkbox in the Eclipse/CDT IDE.

Comment: @krynr: at best the compiler could do a partial check -- whether a virtual function is *obviously* called from a constructor. Checking the call stack at runtime (or a call-stack-like structure, as the questioner proposes) would be more thorough You'd have to test not just that a virtual function has been called with the constructor above you in the call stack, but that it's on the same object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> cat nevercall.cpp             
class Transaction {
public:
    Transaction();
    virtual void logTransaction() const = 0;

    // ...
};

Transaction::Transaction()
{
    //...
    logTransaction();
}

class BuyTransaction: public Transaction {
public:
    virtual void logTransaction() const;

    //...
};

class SellTransaction: public Transaction {
public:
    virtual void logTransaction() const;

    // ...
};

int main()
{
    BuyTransaction b;
}
```

Using `-Weffc++` warns about this if (and only if) `virtual void Transaction::logTransaction() const` is *pure*, as it is in Meyer's sample code:

```
> g++ -Weffc++ nevercall.cpp -o nevercall
nevercall.cpp:1:7: warning: 'class Transaction' has virtual functions and accessible non-virtual destructor [-Wnon-virtual-dtor]
nevercall.cpp: In constructor 'Transaction::Transaction()':
nevercall.cpp:12:20: warning: pure virtual 'virtual void Transaction::logTransaction() const' called from constructor [enabled by default]
nevercall.cpp: At global scope:
nevercall.cpp:15:7: warning: 'class BuyTransaction' has virtual functions and accessible non-virtual destructor [-Wnon-virtual-dtor]
nevercall.cpp:22:7: warning: 'class SellTransaction' has virtual functions and accessible non-virtual destructor [-Wnon-virtual-dtor]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, none of those cover the specific case he asked about. But they are *very* handy. +1 for sharing this gem.

Comment: `pure virtual 'virtual void Transaction::logTransaction() const' called from constructor `. Or have I misunderstood the question?

Comment: His example was (I think) about ordinary virtual functions, not pure virtual functions. [This](http://pastebin.com/smRTS7PU) is what I think he's after. [Or this](http://ideone.com/P6Wpf).

Comment: Ah yes... Good catch! `-Weffc++` won't warn if `virtual void Transaction::logTransaction() const` is not pure.

Comment: Hi all! Thanks for the response anyway.I was looking at boost::type_traits but unfortunately doesn't do the job I want. Is ok to start with -Weffc++ that I agree is very nice.

Answer (score 2):

[PC-Lint](http://www.gimpel.com/html/pcl.htm) will do it!

I ran it on this test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Base
{
public:
        Base() { moo(); }
        virtual ~Base() { ; }
        virtual void moo(void) { printf("Base::moo\n"); }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
        Derived() { ; }
        virtual void moo(void) { printf("Derived::moo\n"); }
};

int main(void)
{
        Derived j; // Outputs 'Base::moo'
}
```

And it complained:

> Warning 1506:  Call to virtual function 'Base::moo(void)' within a constructor or destructor

Comment: Hi David!I like to see PC-Lint mentioned here. Was 10 years ago and still it is one of the best tools around. Great reminder!

Comment: I had that same feeling! I asked a colleague if he knew of any tool that could detect this problem (after neither `gcc` nor `cppcheck` could do it). When he said "PC Lint!", I laughed and said, "Is that still around?!". :)